# Iterating over each row of a data frame column and check if the value exists in another list

Tags: r, list

I have a set of values in a list

```
list2 = c("Ford","Chrysler","Honda","Lexus","Mercedez")
```

and have data frame with let's say 2 columns and am looking to fill `Match_Flag` column based on if the value exists in `list2`.

```
Make Match_Flag 
Ford 
Mercedez
Chrysler
```

Here's my current work:

```
for (i in 1:length(df$Make)){

    if(df$Make[[i]] %in% list2){
       df$Match_Flag == 1
    }
    else {
       df$Match_Flag == 0
    }
}
```

This assignment of 1 and if condition doesn't seem to work and all values are assigned 0s instead. This is slightly different from the other question linked as this involves comparing a list with another list versus checking for an element in the list. Thanks.

Comment: `df$Match_Falg <- as.numeric(df$Make %in% list2)`. No need for a loop.

Comment: that worked! thx.